# In PowerShell, how to list files that do not have an extension, like "dir *." used to in the command prompt?

Tags: powershell

For example, if I have two files

```
foo
foo.txt
```

In the old-fashion command prompt

```
dir *.
```

returns `foo` as desired (along with `.` and `..`).

However the same command in PowerShell returns an empty list. How to circumvent that?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `-Filter` option of the "new" PowerShell's `dir` (a.k.a `Get-ChildItem`):

```
dir -Filter *.
```

The filter can be a relative path

```
dir -Filter .\path\to\*.
```

or it can be combined with a relative or absolute `-Path`

```
dir c:\path\to -Filter *.
```